# Javascript - How to get a list of strings between two characters

Tags: javascript

How can implement a function that returns a list of characters between two characters?

```
const string = "My name is <<firstname>> and I am <<age>>";

const getVariables = (string) => { 
  // How do I implement?
}

console.log(getVariables(string));  // ['firstname', 'age']
```

**PS:** I realize there are multiple answers on how to do something similar, but all of them only work for getting first instance and not all occurrences.

Comment: Regular expressions is your friend

Comment: Show us what you tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is some kind of templating, you can proceed like this:

```js
let format = (str, vars) => 
  str.replace(/<<(\w+)>>/g, (_, w) => vars[w]);
  
//

const tpl = "My name is <<firstname>> and I am <<age>>";

console.log(
  format(tpl, {firstname: 'Bob', age: 33})
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search for string which has the starting pattern and end pattern with look behind and look ahead.

```js
const
    string = "My name is <<firstname>> and I am <<age>>",
    parts = string.match(/(?<=\<\<).*?(?=\>\>)/g);

console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex, group, `matchAll` and get the first group

```js
const string = "My name is <<firstname>>, from <<place>>, and I am <<age>>"

const getVariables = string => {
  return [...string.matchAll(/<<(\w+)>>/g)].map(match => match[1])
}

console.log(getVariables(string))
```